# Show label for location name from Google Maps intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I'm opening Google Maps app from my Android app using intent as follows.

`Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=50.123,-50.456(label)");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
startActivity(mapIntent);`

Google Maps says it's not able to find the address. When I omit the "(label)", it simply finds the lat long point.

Is there a way to display whatever label name I want together with the lat long I specify?

Comment: Works fine for me.  What is the actual label you're using?

Comment: Found the issue. It was the `&`.  It has to be escaped..duh

Comment: @awonderer, Please either update the answer or post the format that has been used to show the label.